# React DragAndDrop - How to make items changing with each other after drop on other items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, drag-and-drop

first time i tried DragAndDrop in react and I need a little help. I did drag and drop item to empty container but i need to make this items changing position after drop on other items too.
Please can you help me how to do this?

My code on sandbox is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-ug2zx?file=/index.js

Blue are containers other are items.

```
class Todo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={"d-flex"}>
        <div className={"d-flex flex-column"}>
          <ItemSlot id={1}> </ItemSlot>
          <ItemSlot id={2}> </ItemSlot>
          <ItemSlot id={3}> </ItemSlot>
        </div>
        <div className={"d-flex flex-column ml-3"}>
          <ItemSlot id={4}>
            <Item id={"i1"} color={"red"} />
          </ItemSlot>
          <ItemSlot id={5}>
            <Item id={"i2"} color={"purple"} />
          </ItemSlot>
          <ItemSlot id={3} color={"green"}>
            <Item id={"i3"} color={"green"} />
          </ItemSlot>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ItemSlot extends Component {
  drop = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const uniqueKey = e.dataTransfer.getData("transfer");
    e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(uniqueKey));
  };

  allowDrop = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        id={this.props.id}
        onDrop={this.drop}
        onDragOver={this.allowDrop}
        style={{
          width: "200px",
          height: "50px",
          backgroundColor: "blue",
          margin: 20 + "px"
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Item extends Component {
  drag = e => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("transfer", this.props.id);
  };

  allowToDrop = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        id={this.props.id}
        draggable={"true"}
        onDragStart={this.drag}
        onDragOver={this.allowToDrop}
        style={{
          width: "200px",
          height: "50px",
          backgroundColor: `${this.props.color}`
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Example i have Purple on position 1 and Red on position 2. I take purple and drop it on position two. Red should automatic go to position 1. This is what i need to do :) Thx

Or in worse case, it will be enough if after drop item1 on other item2, item2 will come back to position when it starts. But first option is better.

Comment: I often discourage the overuse of libraries, but the HTML5 drag-and-drop spec has always been a bit of a train wreck and there are 2 very popular (battle tested) and feature-rich solutions for React that you could use:  **[React Beautiful DnD](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd)** and **[React DnD](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd)**

Comment: What would you recomend me for my case please? I have object behind every item and after draging to slots i have to update this object atributes. Or it doesn't matter which one i will use? anyway thx for recomendations